# Byte compilation error with use-package

Tags: init-file, debugging, use-package, byte-compilation

The beginning of my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file looks like this:

```
;; MELPA
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq package-check-signature nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpy" . "https://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))

;; boostrap 'use-package'
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(use-package windmove
  ;; move cursor between windows
  :demand
  :bind
  (("C-<left>" . windmove-left)
   ("C-<right>" . windmove-right)
   ("C-<up>" . windmove-up)
   ("C-<down>" . windmove-down)))

... more stuff ...
```

I am trying to byte compile my `init.el` file. I execute the following in the terminal, sinde the `~/.emacs.d/` directory:

```
$ emacs --batch --eval '(byte-compile-file "init.el")'
```

The output is:

```
In toplevel form:
init.el:59:1:Warning: ‘("C-<left>" . windmove-left)’ is a malformed function
init.el:59:14:Warning: reference to free variable ‘windmove’
init.el:62:3:Error: Wrong type argument: sequencep, windmove-right
```

Basically, the very first key binding definition fails... and there is also some sort of warning about a free variable. How do I properly byte-compile the `init.el` file - even for the above very simple example (imagine there's nothing else to the `init.el` file)?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a `(require 'use-package)`; without that, Emacs gets confused about use-package and treats it as a function instead of a macro.

Answer (score -1):

A guess is that you need to quote the list after `:bind`:

```
'(("C-<left>" . windmove-left)
  ("C-<right>" . windmove-right)
  ("C-<up>" . windmove-up)
  ("C-<down>" . windmove-down))
```

The error message tells you that the compiler is trying to *evaluate* this as a functional application:

```
(("C-<left>" . windmove-left)
 ("C-<right>" . windmove-right)
 ("C-<up>" . windmove-up)
 ("C-<down>" . windmove-down))
```

That is, it's looking at that as an application of the "function" `("C-<left>" . windmove-left)` to the arguments that are the other elements of that list. It looks as the list as `(FUNCTION ARG1 ARG2 ARG3)`.

Because it's trying to *evaluate* the list instead of taking it as data (i.e., as a list), I assume you need to quote it (`'`). Quoting it prevents evaluation of the list itself; evaluating a quoted list just returns the list.

**UPDATE**

Well, I don't use `use-package`, and know nothing about it. I just know that the error message means the list you have is being interpreted as a functional application. But looking at other questions about `use-package` with `:bind` I see that the list after `:bind` is not supposed to be quoted.

So another guess is that you're missing something after `:demand`, so that `:demand` is acting on `:bind`, and so the list after `:bind` is evaluated.

(Just another guess...)

And finding other examples, it seems that what you're missing after `:demand` is `t`:

```
(use-package windmove
  ;; move cursor between windows
  :demand t
  :bind
  (("C-<left>" . windmove-left)
   ("C-<right>" . windmove-right)
   ("C-<up>" . windmove-up)
   ("C-<down>" . windmove-down)))
```

In sum, each of the keywords (`:demand` and `:bind`) needs to be followed by a value. Because `:demand` was missing its value (`t`) the compiler took the `:bind` after it as the value of `:demand`. And after that there was no keyword but just a list. And that got evaluated as a functional application.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to fix the issue (adding `:demand t`). But interesting observation...

Comment: Just an FYI. The t after :demand, and indeed many other forms like :ensure, are not necessary.